# Run a Java program starting from a class on my classpath

Tags: java, classpath

Is there any way to specify "run the main method of this particular Java class" from the command line, given that the class is known to be in my classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something like

```
java -cp foo.jar MyClass
```

Comment: What if I don't know where the JAR is?

Comment: How is your classpath defined if you know the class is in it but not which jar?

Comment: Actually, I know the name of the Jar, but I don't know its location relative to the location the script is being run. I just know that the classpath environment variable contains the JAR

Comment: If it is in the classpath just run `java MyClass`.

Comment: You can also use `java -verbose MyClass` to see loading information.